# Boolean Algebra A + AB = A

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

Hi I have a question about the following algebra rule

*A + AB = A*

My textbook explains this as follows A + AB = A This rule can be proved as such:

**Step 1:**

***Dustributive Law:***

A + AB = A*1 = A(1+B) Huh...? Where do they get the one(1) from?

***Step 2:***

*1 + B = 1* **{Question:1 + B = B right? so how is this posible(*1 + B = 1*)?}**

***Step 3:***

A + 1 = A

Thus A + AB = A

If anyone can clarify this for me it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I guess * here is AND so I'll go with that: Any rule (A for example) is equivilant to $1 AND A$, because the answer depends on A anyway. The textbook just extended the rule to reach the other side of the equation

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "Any rule (A for example) is equivilant to 1 AND A,

Comment: For each A, A and 1*A has the same truth table.

Comment: What is the title of your textbook, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, note that $A$ and $AB$ have a common factor--namely $A$--and factoring it out, we have $$A+AB=A(1+B)=A(1)=A$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if an expression has a common factor, one of the variables --A-- in his case will hold the value of 1?

Comment: That is the idea. For any variable $A,$ we can always rewrite as $A=A\cdot 1,$ since $1$ is the multiplicative identity. We can also rewrite $A=A\cdot A,$ because of idempotence, but that won't help us, here.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @Cameron I am finally getting it. Last Question then I will close the answer. How do you know when to use A as A=A.1 = 1 and when to use A=A.A

Comment: The amusing (though not very enlightening) answer is: "Go with what works." In many cases, there are several different approaches that will do the job, but in some cases, a particular "slick trick" is required. The best advice I can give you is to practice, practice, practice. If you're interested, you can find several answers with various useful tricks [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a28900%20%5bboolean-algebra%5d).

Comment: In particular, we can't (in general) simplify $A+B$ any further, so writing $A=A\cdot A$ won't help us, here. However, $1+B=B$ *will* help us.

Comment: Oops! I just noticed an error in my last comment. It should read "$1+B=1,$" not "$1+B=B.$"

Answer (score 0):

$A + AB = (A * 1) + (A * B) = A * (1 + B) = A * 1 = A$.

$A = A * 1$ because $1$ is an identity for $*$, and so $x * 1 = x$ for all $x$. There's not really much more to it.

Comment: Ok so you are saying if I see * then A*A is the same as A*1...? Is that correct? Im sorry im really struggling to understand how to factor this out. Thank you for your help

Comment: There is no $A * A$ in this at all -- I'm not really sure where you're getting that from. $A$, however, is the same as $A * 1$ (Both are, in fact, the same as $A * A$, but that isn't relevant here.)