# What is meant by $AB$ in boolean algebra?

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

I am endeavoring to teach myself Boolean Algebra. Oh what fun! From the questions I've read on this site, one of the *most common* notations I've seen is $AB$ (examples: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528110/boolean-algebra-a-ab-a), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076857/boolean-simplification-of-abc-abc-abc-a-bc-abc), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076521/how-to-this-simplify-boolean-expression)). Problem is: I have no idea what this means. At all.

Any answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: @copper.hat That's answer worthy, please answer!

Comment: Done :-) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means conjunction or 'and', $A \land B$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept when the time becomes available!

Comment: No worries! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hey, here's a random question: Is `{}{}{}` your signature or something? As in, \${}{}{}\$

Comment: No, just a way of 'getting around' the minimum number of characters in a comment. Not much point really, as it requires typing more. Just because I can :-).

Comment: Ohhhhhhh that makes so much sense. Well-played!